# Auto scroll div based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to automatically scroll a div based on mouse position using jQuery.

If you see this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xWcXt/3/), you can see a number of images that are horizontally ordered in a div that is scrollable:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="propertyThumbnails">
        <img src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.millport.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Flower-festival.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
#propertyThumbnails {
    background: #666;
    height: 80px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#propertyThumbnails img {
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-right: 0;
    opacity: 0.6; 
}
```

I found out that you can use `$("#container").scrollLeft(position)` to set the position of the scroller but I want to do it based on the mouse position of the parent.  So that when the mouse is fully to the right hand side, the right most image displays, and when the mouse is fully left, the left most image displays.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly scroll an overflowing div based on mouse position within its container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635276/how-to-properly-scroll-an-overflowing-div-based-on-mouse-position-within-its-con)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A slightly different way to achieve what you need:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $(window).load(function() {

    var $gal = $("#propertyThumbnails"),
      galW = $gal.outerWidth(true),
      galSW = $gal[0].scrollWidth,
      wDiff = (galSW / galW) - 1, // widths difference ratio
      mPadd = 60, // Mousemove Padding
      damp = 20, // Mousemove response softness
      mX = 0, // Real mouse position
      mX2 = 0, // Modified mouse position
      posX = 0,
      mmAA = galW - (mPadd * 2), // The mousemove available area
      mmAAr = (galW / mmAA); // get available mousemove fidderence ratio

    $gal.mousemove(function(e) {
      mX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
      mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay" 
      $gal.scrollLeft(posX * wDiff);
    }, 10);

  });

});
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 260px;
}

#propertyThumbnails {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  height: 262px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#propertyThumbnails img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="propertyThumbnails">

    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400/0bf" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400/f0b" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400/0fb" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400/b0f" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/600x400/bf0" />

  </div>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

where `mPadd` is the area (in PX, at the left and right border zone) without any sensitivity to prevent user frustrations :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I couldnt get this to work with my code http://www.appletonthorne.co.uk/new/viewproperty.html

Comment: Finally got yours working, it is very nice... could only get it working on the thumbnails container though...

Comment: :) if you prest attention I use `$gal.mousemove(function(e) {` instead of `$gal` you can use the parent container and tweak the code.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you for your answer, this worked amazingly! A question: is possible activate the scroll only when the mouse is on the limit left and right of my zone (div)?

Comment: @Giobbo in such case you need and entirely different code. Also, you can use two transparent DIV elements that would trigger a scroll

Comment: how to do vertical scroll effect?

Comment: @JustCode seems a simple question, in the code replace X with Y and Width with Height, W with H, left with top....

Answer (score 3):

this should at least get you headed in the right direction.

```
var parent = $('#parent');
var img = $('img:first-child');

parent.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX
    img.css('margin-left',-mouseX/parent.width()*100);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xWcXt/4/

Comment: This works perfectly, however when I implement it into my site, it didnt scroll to show all thumbnails - see here: http://www.appletonthorne.co.uk/new/viewproperty.html

Comment: You'll have to do some of the math yourself, I just wanted to give you enough of the basic functionality to get you started, not do it for you.

Comment: Got it: 100 should be `$('#propertyThumbnails')[0].scrollWidth - parent.width() - 3`

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help, again :p

Comment: WORKS, this answer needs to be higher up. Google is full of deal links... Great job, thankyou