# Horizontal scroll on mouse position (Mouse Padding)

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am working on a carousel that will work on mouse scroll. I made one, but it must go until the end of the left or right to see the first/last post and this is a little bit frustrating. What I want is to make mouse padding so that before I go till the end of the screen (left and right) with mouse over to show me the posts.

I want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308129/auto-scroll-div-based-on-mouse-position) (solution from Roko), but I can't implement it in my project.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var EASING = 1,
    FPS = 220,
    $paneTarget = $('#scroll'),
    $paneContainer = $('.oxy-posts'),
    windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    containerWidth = 0,
    maxScroll = 0,
    posX = 0, // Keep track of the container position with posX
    targetX = 0,
    animInterval = false; // No interval is set by default

  $paneTarget.find('li').each(function() {
    containerWidth += $(this).width();
    $paneContainer.width(containerWidth);
  });

  // Set maximum amount the container can scroll
  // negative because we're gonna scroll to left
  maxScroll = -(containerWidth - windowWidth);

  // This gets called from the setInterval and handles the animating of the scroll container
  function animationLoop() {
    var dx = targetX - posX, // Difference
      vx = dx * EASING; // Velocity

    // Add velocity to x position and update css with new position
    posX += vx;
    $paneContainer.css({
      left: posX
    });

    // When end target is reached stop the interval
    if (Math.round(posX) === targetX) {
      clearInterval(animInterval);
      animInterval = false;
    }
  }

  function startAnimation() {
    // Only start animation interval when it's not already running
    if (!animInterval) {
      animInterval = setInterval(animationLoop, 100 / FPS);
    }
  }

  $paneTarget.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    // Calculate the new x position for the scroll container
    targetX = Math.round((event.pageX / windowWidth) * maxScroll);

    startAnimation();
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    maxScroll = -(containerWidth - windowWidth);

    // OPTIONAL:
    // Move scrollpane to original position on resize
    targetX = 0;
    // Animate to newly set target
    startAnimation();
  });

});
```

```css
#scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 40px solid #f3f3f3;
}

.oxy-posts {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#scroll .oxy-posts {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.oxy-posts li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  width: calc((100vh - 100px) * 400 / 724);
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  display: block;
}

.oxy-posts li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.051);
  transition: transform 3.5s ease .3s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.oxy-posts .text-container {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  transition: bottom .5s ease;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#scroll .oxy-post-padding {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc((100vh - 100px) * 400 / 724);
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-out, transform .3s ease-out, opacity .2s ease-out;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

#scroll .oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out opacity, .5s ease-in-out max-height;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-padding:hover .oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio {
  opacity: .8;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 2em;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-top: 200px;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,1) 300px);*/
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  text-align: left;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out opacity, .5s ease-in-out max-height;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-padding:hover .oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 400px;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-content {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
}

#scroll .oxy-post-content p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll" class="oxy-easy-posts oxy-posts-grid">
  <div class="oxy-posts" style="width: 2740px; left: -44px;">
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="oxy-post">

      <div class="oxy-post-padding">

        <div class="oxy-post-image-fixed-ratio" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),url(http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Move_Visuels_horizontal_A5-3.jpg);"></div>

        <div class="oxy-post-wrap">

          <a class="oxy-post-title" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/home_kacheln/laden-ohne-abo/">What is Lorem Ipsum?</a>

          <div class="oxy-post-content-and-link-wrap">
            <div class="oxy-post-content">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a id="link_button-109-25" class="ct-link-button move_button" href="http://lfrowkhf.preview.infomaniak.website/move-light/">Jetzt für Read More </a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gencdoda/Lrtud3cf/9/)

Comment: Please insert your [code](/help/mwe) to your question from the fiddle!

Comment: Every code and implementation is different one from another, based on someone else example we cannot further assist you. Please provide some [mre] in order to be able to provide any feedback or support.

Comment: @HasanPatel i provided an example that i saved on fiddle the code that you see above is what i did. It is working great i just can't figure out how to add mouse padding. Thanks for your Support!